# How to create array of String pairs correcly?

Tags: java, android

I need to store simple array with String pairs. I make it with this:

```
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;

private static Pair<String, String>[] sDataList = new Pair[]{
            new Pair("source1", "result1"),
            new Pair("source2", "result2"),
            new Pair("source3", "result3")
            };
```

And get two warnings:

1. `Unchecked assignment: 'android.support.v4.util.Pair[]' to 'android.support.v4.util.Pair<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>[]'`
2. `Unchecked call to 'Pair<F, S>' as a member of raw type 'android.support.v4.util.Pair'`

How to implement it correctly?

Comment: Arrays and generics doesn't work well. Consider using `List` instead like `Arrays.asList(your,elements)`

Comment: @stark, note the [java] tag

Comment: Hi BArtWell I am facing similar kind of issue, are you able to found any solution on this?  Please let me know the solution?

Comment: Hi @umesh, no. As I know here is no way to implement this. But you can use your own class extends Pair<String, String> or just use List instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize array elements like this

```
new Pair<String, String>("source1", "result1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Pair with:

```
new Pair<String, String>("source1", "result1");
```

Will lead you to another warning.

The correct way to create Pair objects, is to use the create method ([Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/Pair.html#create(A,%20B)))

```
Pair.create("source1", "result1");
```